# What is the significance of repeating certain pasukim?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, prayer-book, nusach-sefard, tefilat-haderech

During various parts of davening, we repeat certain pasukim, be it three or more times. What is the explanation for this practice?

For example: the beginning of Mincha and Maariv, during Kriyas Shema Al Hamita, and Tefilas Haderech.

Comment: What do we repeat in Mincha or Tefilas Haderech?

Comment: @shmosel See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard,_Weekday_Mincha,_Korbanot.11) and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard,_Blessings,_Traveler's_Prayer.4). These nuances are not present in every nusach.